# How to resolve a Go type error when trying to return an object array in my GRPC service?

Tags: go, types, service, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to create a basic GRPC Server in go, but there is a type error that I don't understand how to resolve. A function makes a request to an external API and I would like my GRPC GreetService's Greet function to return the array.

The type error is below:

> cannot use result.Inventory (variable of type []InventoryData) as []*proto.DealerInventory_InventoryData value

My GRPC Service's Greet function returns a Proto Buffer message:

```
func (s *Server) Greet(ctx context.Context, in *pb.GreetRequest) (*pb.DealerInventory, error) {
    result := getInventoryData()
    return &pb.DealerInventory{
        Inventory: result.Inventory,
    }, nil
```

My *getInventoryData()* should return an array of objects of type *DealerInventory*:

```
type InventoryData struct {
    DHCost          string
    DealerNumber    string
    ModelYear       string
    ExteriorColor   string
    InteriorColor   string
    ModelGroupName  string
    Transmission    string
    ModelMSRP       string
    NumberOnSite    uint32
    NumberInTransit uint32
}

type DealerInventory struct {
    Inventory              []InventoryData
    Vehiclemodelseriesname string
    ZipCodeSent            string
}
```

And my proto message looks like this:

```
message DealerInventory {
    message InventoryData {
        string DHCost = 1;
        string DealerNumber = 2;
        string ModelYear = 3;
        string ExteriorColor = 4;
        string InteriorColor = 5;
        string ModelGroupName = 6;
        string Transmission = 7;
        string ModelMSRP = 8;
        uint32 NumberOnSite = 9;
        uint32 NumberInTransit = 10;
    }
    repeated InventoryData Inventory = 3;
    string Vehiclemodelseriesname = 4;
    string ZipCodeSent = 5;
}
```

The type error can be reproduced by cloning the project's [example/typeError branch](https://github.com/thanders/dealership-inventory/tree/example/typeError) and opening the [greet.go](https://github.com/thanders/dealership-inventory/blob/example/typeError/greet/server/greet.go) file in your IDE.

I'd like to know why I am getting the type error and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the error is saying:

```
./greet.go:12:14: cannot use result.Inventory (variable of type []InventoryData) as type []*"github.com/thanders/dealership-inventory/greet/proto".DealerInventory_InventoryData in struct literal
```

So this indicates that you are attempting to use a variable of type `[]InventoryData` (where `InventoryData` is defined defined in package `main`) as a `[]*DealerInventory_InventoryData` (where `DealerInventory_InventoryData` is defined in package `github.com/thanders/dealership-inventory/greet/proto`).

Go will make no attempt to convert between these two structures (by design details like this are not hidden from the developer). This would not work even if the two `struct`s had the same name and fields. For example you cannot do:

```
x := DealerInventory{IsValidZip: true}
var y pb.DealerInventory
y = x
```

(this would result in the error `cannot use x (variable of type DealerInventory) as type "github.com/thanders/dealership-inventory/greet/proto".DealerInventory in assignment`).

If you want to structure your application in this way then you will need to convert between the two data types with something like:

```golang
result := getInventoryData()
di := make([]*pb.DealerInventory_InventoryData, len(result.Inventory))
for i, r := range result.Inventory {
    di[i] = &pb.DealerInventory_InventoryData{
        DHCost:          r.DHCost,
        DealerNumber:    r.DealerNumber,
        ModelYear:       r.ModelYear,
        ExteriorColor:   r.ExteriorColor,
        InteriorColor:   r.InteriorColor,
        ModelGroupName:  r.ModelGroupName,
        Transmission:    r.Transmission,
        ModelMSRP:       r.ModelMSRP,
        NumberOnSite:    r.NumberOnSite,
        NumberInTransit: r.NumberInTransit,
    }
}

return &pb.DealerInventory{
    IsValidZip:             result.IsValidZip,
    Dealers:                result.Dealers,
    Inventory:              di,
    Vehiclemodelseriesname: result.Vehiclemodelseriesname,
    ZipCodeSent:            result.ZipCodeSent,
}, nil
```

Alternatively, consider whether defining a separate `InventoryData` & `DealerInventory` in `main` is providing a benefit (`getInventoryData` could return a `*pb.DealerInventory`).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response and that very useful example! I'm new to Go and trying to learn. I like your idea about having getInventoryData return a *pb.DealerInventory. I'll try that. Thanks!